Deriving the Yukawa potential from the field of a screened charge
I am trying to derive the Yukawa potential from the electric field of a screened positive point charge, which is
$$
\vec{E}(\vec{r}) = \frac{q}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{e^{-kr}(kr+1)}{r^2}\hat{r}.
$$
The simplest way to do it I think is to use
$$
V(\vec{r}) = -\int_{\mathcal{O}}^{\vec{r}}\vec{E}\cdot d\vec{r} = -\int_{\infty}^r\frac{q}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{e^{-kr'}(kr'+1)}{r'^2}dr' \\
 = -\frac{q}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\left(\int_{\infty}^r\frac{ke^{-kr'}}{r'}dr' + \int_{\infty}^r\frac{e^{-kr'}}{r'^2}dr' \right)
$$
but these integrals are advanced and I don't know how to solve them.
I have also computed the corresponding charge distribution $\rho$ from the field through Gauss' law but I don't know if I can compute the potential from
$$
V(\vec{r}) = \frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\int\int\int_{volume}\frac{\rho(\vec{r}')}{|\vec{r}-\vec{r}'|}d\tau'
$$
because I think $\rho$ extends to infinity meaning the integral would diverge.
This is an exercise related to the second chapter of Griffiths (not in the book itself though), so I am looking for a way to solve it that doesn't use Poisson's equation and the methods of solving it.

What is the associated charge denisty that you are given?  Or are you relying on Coulomb's law to calcuate it from the electric field?

Consider the integral
$$
\int_{\infty}^r\frac{ke^{-kr'}}{r'}dr'.
$$
This integral doesn't have an elementary solution (I don't think), but you can still use elementary techniques to transform it as follows: Perform an integration by parts, with $u = 1/r'$ and $dv = k e^{-kr'}$.  We then have $v = -e^{-kr'}$ and $du = - dr'/{r'}^2$, and so
$$
\int_{\infty}^r\frac{ke^{-kr'}}{r'}dr' = \left[ -\frac{e^{-kr'}}{r'} \right]_{\infty}^r - \int_{\infty}^r\frac{e^{-kr'}}{{r'}^2}dr',
$$
and so
$$
 \int_{\infty}^r\frac{ke^{-kr'}}{r'}dr' + \int_{\infty}^r\frac{e^{-kr'}}{r'^2}dr' = -\frac{e^{-kr}}{r}
$$
as desired.

I get $$-\frac{d}{dr}\left(\frac{e^{-kr}}{r} \right) = -\left( \frac{-kre^{-kr}-e^{-kr}}{r^2} \right) = \frac{e^{-kr}(kr+1)}{r^2}$$
but I do find that the those two integrals cancel due to the minus sign given by $$\frac{d}{dr}(r^{-1}) = -r^{-2} $$

Hmm, I seem to have made an even number of sign errors.  Let me edit this.

There we go.  I had accidentally dropped the minus sign in the exponent when I took the derivative the first time — mea culpa.

Let the radial component of the electric field $E_r(r)$ be given by
$$E_r(r)=\frac{q}{4\pi\varepsilon_0}\frac{(1+kr)e^{-kr}}{r^2}\tag1$$
The potential function, $\phi(r)$, satisfies the differnetial equation
$$\frac{\partial \phi(r)}{\partial r}=E_r(r)\tag2$$
Using $(1)$ in $(2)$ and integrating we find that
$$\begin{align}
\phi(r)&=\int^r E_r(r')\,dr'+C\\\\
&=\frac{q}{4\pi\varepsilon_0} \int^r \frac{(1+kr')e^{-kr'}}{r'^2}\,dr'+C\\\\
&=\frac{q}{4\pi\varepsilon_0} \int^r \frac{e^{-kr'}}{r'^2}\,dr'+\frac{q}{4\pi\varepsilon_0} \int^r \frac{ke^{-kr'}}{r'}\,dr'+C\\\\
&\overbrace{=}^{IBP}-\frac{q}{4\pi\varepsilon_0}\frac{e^{-kr}}{r}+\frac{q}{4\pi\varepsilon_0}\left(-\int^r \frac{ke^{-kr'}}{r'}\,dr'+\int^r \frac{ke^{-kr'}}{r'}\,dr'\right) +C\\\\
&=-\frac{q}{4\pi\varepsilon_0}\frac{e^{-kr}}{r}+C
\end{align}$$
Inasmuch as we set the potential at infinity to $0$, we find
$$\phi(r)=-\frac{q}{4\pi\varepsilon_0}\frac{e^{-kr}}{r}$$
as was to be shown!
